# Stack Exchange sites no longer neatly fit a 1050 pixel wide (portrait mode) screen

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

I like to open most sites on my portrait mode (1050 x 1680) monitor.  A few days ago, Stack Exchange sites started requiring a horizontal scroll bar when opened on this monitor in each of my installed browsers. (Firefox, Chrome, I.E.)

1. Did we gain any shiny new functionality to justify the wider screen requirements or is this simply a function of designers only considering presentation on landscape mode monitors?
2. Is it reasonable for the site to have it's width requirements reduced?

Comment: My advice is to use Stylish/Greasemonkey to fix. The linked question has CSS a-plenty.